# What is the meaning of 刚一通过 here please?

Tags: meaning

当年，《中华人民共和国商标法》刚一通过，美国的《读者文摘》就立即为其中文文版《读者文摘》注册，并得到了相关部门的批准。

Does ‘刚一通过’ mean (a law) just passed through parliament , or in this case, the Peoples Congress in Beijing and ratified?

Answer (score 2):

**刚一**

ABC

> ADV. (副词)
>
> just when; as soon as

CC-CEDICT

> 1 to be just about to
>
> 2 to have just started to

KEY

> as soon as

当年，《中华人民共和国商标法》刚一通过，美国的《读者文摘》就立即为其中文文版《读者文摘》注册，并得到了相关部门的批准。

At that time, just when the "Trademark Law of the People’s Republic of China" was passed "Reader's Digest", as American company, immediately registered the Chinese version of it's publication (读者文摘) and received approval from all relative departments.

Answer (score 1):

Here, “the law 刚一通过" is a colloquial/informal expression. It means the law is passed / enacted.

刚: just

一: once, immediately

通过: passed